# Page break is not working in Apache POI XWPF

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText("TITLE");
    run.addCarriageReturn();
    run.setText("some text and stuff here");
    run.addCarriageReturn();                 
    run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
    run.addBreak(BreakType.TEXT_WRAPPING);   //cancels effect of page break
     run = paragraph.createRun();    //create new run
    run.setText("more text");
    run.addCarriageReturn();
    run.setText("one more line");
    document.write(fos);
    fos.close();
```

The above code is not working. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Apache POI is this with? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: am using apache poi 3.9

Comment: And what happens when you upgrade to a more recent version?

Comment: More recent versions means 3.12 or else

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine with below code

```
XWPFParagraph para = document.getLastParagraph();
```

XWPFRun run = para.createRun();
 run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);